# Losing characters when converting byte array to hexadecimal

Tags: c#, string, hex

I wanted to convert a random byte array to hex, there is no error but let me show the output:

The first output is as example: D2C13E9C4C9378C7

And the second which should be the same with spaces: D2 C1 3 9C 4C 93 78 C7  <-- it just removed the E after the 3, does anyone know why?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // with string interpolation
            Random rnd = new Random();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
            rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
            long l = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
            Console.WriteLine($"Without To Hex Method: {l:X}");
            string hexstring = ToHex(bytes);
            Console.WriteLine($"With To Hex Method: {hexstring}");


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string ToHex(byte[] arr)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            var arr1 = arr.Reverse().ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append($"{arr1[i]:X2} ");
            }

            sb.Remove(arr.Length - 1, 1);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: You're removing the character at `arr.Length - 1`. `arr.Length` is 8, which is not at all the length of the string you just generated. return sb.ToString().TrimRight() instead.

Comment: I would guess an Off-by-one error.

Comment: @Christopher Off by a factor of three.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ah i noticed the error. I wanted the string length not the length of the array. But thanks anywea

Comment: @EdPlunkett it works now i just forgot that the string isnt as long as the array.

Comment: i know but i wanted to reverse the array

Comment: You can trimend() instead of remove char, it will prevent bugs since you don't check length.

Comment: Olivier is correct, there's no such thing as TrimRight(), it's TrimEnd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `sb.Remove(arr.Length - 1, 1)` : `arr.Length` is not `sb.Length` because chars are 2 bytes so you losted some char near the middle of the left half.

You can use that:

```
static public string ToHex(byte[] array)
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  array = array.Reverse().ToArray();
  for ( int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++ )
  {
    builder.Append($"{array[i]:X2} ");
  }
  return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```

But reversing the array is useless and a loss of speed and memory since you can downcount the loop:

```
static public string ToHex(byte[] array)
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  for ( int index = array.Length - 1; index >= 0; index-- )
  {
    builder.Append($"{array[i]:X2} ");
  }
  return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
}
```